# MySQL malfunction? NOT IN and LEFT JOIN return different results

Tags: mysql

We have 2 tables. Table "list" has **1114** lines. Table "**companies**" has 1094 lines. The tables have 1082 common lines. When I look for the lines that are not common between the tables, **LEFT JOIN** returns the correct result but NOT IN does not.

There are absolute **no nulls** in the relevant columns. The values returned by **LEFT JOIN** (which as mentioned are not null) belong only to one but not the other table as one would expect.

The tables are **`InnoDB`**, the relevant columns are both `varchar(255)` and each has an index.

Can someone help explain this peculiar behavior?

Below are the queries with their results:

**Correct results:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM list l 
LEFT JOIN companies c 
ON l.Full_Company_Name = c.Full_Company_Name 
WHERE c.Full_Company_Name IS NULL

Array
(
    [COUNT(*)] => 32
)

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  companies c 
LEFT JOIN list l
ON l.Full_Company_Name = c.Full_Company_Name 
WHERE l.Full_Company_Name IS NULL

Array
(
    [COUNT(*)] => 12
)
```

**Unexpected results:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  companies c 
WHERE c.Full_Company_Name NOT IN
(SELECT l.Full_Company_Name FROM list l)

Array
(
    [COUNT(*)] => 11
)

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  list l
WHERE l.Full_Company_Name NOT IN
(SELECT c.Full_Company_Name FROM companies c )

Array
(
    [COUNT(*)] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There was one such case which we deleted but the problem persisted.

Comment: Are the keys on `Full_Company_Name` unique or normal?

Comment: They are normal but we have ascertained that the values are indeed unique by running SELECT Full_Company_Name, count(\*) c FROM list group by Full_Company_Name having c>1 ; and  SELECT Full_Company_Name, count(\*) c FROM companies group by Full_Company_Name having c>1  which both return 0 results.

Comment: Check the charset and collation of your datatypes (case (in-)sensitive, utf8 vs latin). There might be some autocast involved. Also try `select *` and look at the values (e.g. if they have special characters) and try those directly in the `not in`-query (e.g. `NOT IN (SELECT 'Stack Exchange Inc')`

Comment: This seems to have been our problem. The problem was solved as soon as we deleted some records with greek and special characters. We will look into our charsets & collations. Thank you Solarfare!

Comment: Why not `NOT EXISTS` instead of `LEFT JOIN` imitation?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have duplicates.

If list is something like:

```
A,B,C,A
```

And companies:

```
A,B,C,D,E,A
```

Then a left join of list on companies gives you 6 results.

A not in, however, will give you 3 or 0 depending on which way round you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you. As mentioned above we have no duplicates.

Comment: Can you provide a reduced data set that exhibits the same issue?